# Why can't I run query twice in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code for running a MySQL query from PHP:

**mysqli_connect.php**

```php
    <?php
        DEFINE ('DB_USER', [my_username]);
        DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', [my_password]);
        DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    
        $databases = array();
        $db_school = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 'db_school')
        OR die('Could not connect to MySQL.db_school');
        $databases['db_school'] = $db_school;
    
        $db_family_finance = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 'db_family_finance')
        OR die('Could not connect to MySQL.db_family_finance');
        $databases['db_family_finance'] = $db_family_finance;
    ?>
```

**get_mysql_data.php**

```php
    <?php    
        function query_database($query) {
            require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');
    
            $response = mysqli_query($db_school, $query);
    
            if ($response) {
                echo "ran query!<br>";
            } else {
                echo "couldn't run query!<br>";
            }
        
            return $response;
        }
    
        query_database("SELECT * FROM tests"); //prints out "ran query!"
        query_database("SELECT * FROM tests"); //prints out "couldn't run query!"
    ?>
```

I am running the same function twice. The first time it returns what I want it to. The second time it doesn't. Why would it do this?

I made a few changes to the code as seen above and I now get this printed to the screen:

```
ran query!

Notice: Undefined variable: db_school in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\tutorials\get_mysql_data.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\tutorials\get_mysql_data.php on line 6
couldn't run query!
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of `mysqli_error()` (e.g. in the else "couldn't run query"-bit)?

Comment: The `@` in front of the methods will suppress errors. You should remove it, at the very least for debugging.

Comment: What is the side effect of using require_once inside a function? It's a bit like the connection isn't being established on the 2nd and subsequent calls... Because you've used @ which is BAD, you are masking any errors being reported.

Comment: When I add `echo mysqli_error($db_school) . "<br>";` to the `else` I get this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: db_school in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\tutorials\get_mysql_data.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\tutorials\get_mysql_data.php on line 11`

Comment: The mysqli_error() needs to get the connection as first argument. Judging from your code above: `mysqli_error($databases['db_school']);` or `$db_school` Also it seems that by moving the script you messed up the scope and it can't find `$db_school` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you include a file inside a function, the scope of all variables, constants etc are local to the function.

Therefore, the first invocation the `mysqli_connect.php` is included and everything works.

In the second invocation, the `mysqli_connect.php` is **NOT** included because of the `require_once`.  Inside the function, this time, those constants and variables do not exist.

This is an example of how to fix it, depending on what you are doing elsewhere.

**Here you declare $dbschool global - this is not generally a good idea.**

```php
<?php    
    require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');

    function query_database($query) {
        global $db_school;
        $response = mysqli_query($db_school, $query);

        if ($response) {
            echo "ran query!<br>";
        } else {
            echo "couldn't run query!<br>";
        }

        return $response;
    }

    query_database("SELECT * FROM tests"); //prints out "ran query!"
    query_database("SELECT * FROM tests"); //prints out "couldn't run query!"
?>
```

or

**Here you pass the database to the function**

````php
<?php    
    require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');

    function query_database($database, $query) {
        $response = mysqli_query($database, $query);

        if ($response) {
            echo "ran query!<br>";
        } else {
            echo "couldn't run query!<br>";
        }

        return $response;
    }

    query_database($db_school, "SELECT * FROM tests"); //prints out "ran query!"
    query_database($db_school, "SELECT * FROM tests"); //prints out "couldn't run query!"
?>
```php
````